# Proper width Alignment of child table inside parent table in HTML

Tags: html, css, nested

I have created a collapsible HTML nested table.
But i am not able to set the proper width after so many futile efforts.
My child table is not fitting to my parent table's head.

Here is the code snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/preetigupta617/bpLkdx13/

Code:
HTML

```
<head>
<script>
$('.content').css('display','none');
    $( ".collapsible" ).click(function() {
         id = $(this).attr('id');
         num = id.split("_").pop();
        // document.getElementById("mytable_"+num).classList.toggle("show");
          if(document.getElementById("mytable_"+num).style.display=='none') {
              document.getElementById("mytable_"+num).style.display= 'block';
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById("mytable_"+num).style.display= 'none'
          }
         console.log(num);
         console.log(document.getElementById("mytable_"+num).innerHTML);
</script>
  <style>
   table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; width:310px;}
   table td {border:solid 1px #fab; width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;}
    /* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */
.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
      <table style='width:80%;margin:0 auto;' border='1' bordercolor='BLACK'>               
        <thead >                                                                             
         <tr class='w3-cyan'><th>S.no</th><th>Command</th><th>Failure Reasons</th><th>Testcase Affected</th><th>Response</th></tr></thead>
<tr id='myBtn_1' class='collapsible'><td>1</td><td colspan=4>build_model</td></tr>                                                        
<tr >                                                                                                                                     
<td colspan=1></td><td colspan=1></td>                                                                                                    
<td  id='mytable_1' class='content' colspan=3><table>                                                                                     
<tr><td>MACHINE_ERROR,OTHER_INFO,WARNINGS,PATTERN_VAR</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/build_model-MACHINE_ERROR-OTHER_INFO-WARNINGS-PATTERN_VAR'>1</a></td><td> Regold</td></tr>                                                       
</table></td></tr>                                                                                                                          
<tr id='myBtn_2' class='collapsible'><td>2</td><td colspan=4>build_testmode</td></tr>                                                       
<tr >                                                                                                                                       
<td colspan=1></td><td colspan=1></td>                                                                                                      
<td  id='mytable_2' class='content' colspan=3><table>                                                                                       
<tr><td>OTHER_INFO,COVERAGE_VAR</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/build_testmode-OTHER_INFO-COVERAGE_VAR'>1</a></td><td> Open CCR</td></tr>                                                                                              
<tr><td>CORE,TESTCASE_ERRORS,CRITICAL_ERRORS,MACHINE_ERROR,PATTERN_VAR,COVERAGE_VAR</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/build_testmode-CORE-TESTCASE_ERRORS-CRITICAL_ERRORS-MACHINE_ERROR-PATTERN_VAR-COVERAGE_VAR'>1</a></td><td> Fix Testcase</td></tr>                                                                                                                              
</table></td></tr>                                                                                                                          
<tr id='myBtn_3' class='collapsible'><td>3</td><td colspan=4>commit_tests</td></tr>                                                         
<tr >                                                                                                                                       
<td colspan=1></td><td colspan=1></td>                                                                                                      
<td  id='mytable_3' class='content' colspan=3><table>                                                                                       
<tr><td>MACHINE_ERROR,WARNINGS</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/commit_tests-MACHINE_ERROR-WARNINGS'>1</a></td><td> Rerun</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr id='myBtn_4' class='collapsible'><td>4</td><td colspan=4>create_logic_tests</td></tr>
<tr >
<td colspan=1></td><td colspan=1></td>
<td  id='mytable_4' class='content' colspan=3><table>
<tr><td>CORE,OTHER_INFO,COVERAGE_VAR</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/create_logic_tests-CORE-OTHER_INFO-COVERAGE_VAR'>1</a></td><td> Regold</td></tr>
<tr><td>CORE,CRITICAL_ERRORS,MACHINE_ERROR,OTHER_INFO,WARNINGS,SEVERE,PATTERN_VAR,COVERAGE_VAR</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/create_logic_tests-CORE-CRITICAL_ERRORS-MACHINE_ERROR-OTHER_INFO-WARNINGS-SEVERE-PATTERN_VAR-COVERAGE_VAR'>1</a></td><td> Rerun</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr id='myBtn_5' class='collapsible'><td>5</td><td colspan=4>diagnose_failures</td></tr>
<tr >
<td colspan=1></td><td colspan=1></td>
<td  id='mytable_5' class='content' colspan=3><table>
<tr><td>TESTCASE_ERRORS,CRITICAL_ERRORS,PATTERN_VAR,COVERAGE_VAR</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/diagnose_failures-TESTCASE_ERRORS-CRITICAL_ERRORS-PATTERN_VAR-COVERAGE_VAR'>1</a></td><td> Rerun</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr id='myBtn_6' class='collapsible'><td>6</td><td colspan=4>verify_test_structures</td></tr>
<tr >
<td colspan=1></td><td colspan=1></td>
<td  id='mytable_6' class='content' colspan=3><table>
<tr><td>TESTCASE_ERRORS,MACHINE_ERROR,OTHER_INFO,WARNINGS,SEVERE,COVERAGE_VAR</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/verify_test_structures-TESTCASE_ERRORS-MACHINE_ERROR-OTHER_INFO-WARNINGS-SEVERE-COVERAGE_VAR'>1</a></td><td> Open CCR</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr id='myBtn_7' class='collapsible'><td>7</td><td colspan=4>write_toggle_gram</td></tr>
<tr >
<td colspan=1></td><td colspan=1></td>
<td  id='mytable_7' class='content' colspan=3><table>
<tr><td>CORE</td><td><a href='http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/write_toggle_gram-CORE'>1</a></td><td> Fix Testcase</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
</table>  
</body>
```

PS:You can also use the jsfiddle link i have given in post too.
    The foldable HTML table is working in actual but not in jsfiddle site.

But i want help only in case of css,i.e i want to set the child table in last 3 columns properly.How can i achieve that?
I tried , but end up only scratching my head .

Thanks in advance !!

[[Output with this current code][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPHhw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPHhw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
$(".collapsible").click(function() {
  $(this).next('tr').toggle();
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

th {
  border: solid 1px;
}

table td {
  border: solid 1px #fab;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

table table {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */

.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.collapsible+tr:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  display: none
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */

.content {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-card w3-round w3-pink">
  <h1>
    <center>Regression Results</center>
  </h1>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="w3-cyan">
      <th>S.no</th>
      <th>Command</th>
      <th>Failure Reasons</th>
      <th>Testcase Affected</th>
      <th>Response</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="collapsible">
      <td>1</td>
      <td colspan="4">build_model</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="content" colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>MACHINE_ERROR,OTHER_INFO,WARNINGS,PATTERN_VAR</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/build_model-MACHINE_ERROR-OTHER_INFO-WARNINGS-PATTERN_VAR">1</a></td>
              <td> Regold</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsible">
      <td>2</td>
      <td colspan="4">build_testmode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="content" colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>OTHER_INFO,COVERAGE_VAR</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/build_testmode-OTHER_INFO-COVERAGE_VAR">1</a></td>
              <td> Open CCR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>CORE,TESTCASE_ERRORS,CRITICAL_ERRORS,MACHINE_ERROR,PATTERN_VAR,COVERAGE_VAR</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/build_testmode-CORE-TESTCASE_ERRORS-CRITICAL_ERRORS-MACHINE_ERROR-PATTERN_VAR-COVERAGE_VAR">1</a></td>
              <td> Fix Testcase</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsible">
      <td>3</td>
      <td colspan="4">commit_tests</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="content" colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>MACHINE_ERROR,WARNINGS</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/commit_tests-MACHINE_ERROR-WARNINGS">1</a></td>
              <td> Rerun</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsible">
      <td>4</td>
      <td colspan="4">create_logic_tests</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="content" colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>CORE,OTHER_INFO,COVERAGE_VAR</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/create_logic_tests-CORE-OTHER_INFO-COVERAGE_VAR">1</a></td>
              <td> Regold</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>CORE,CRITICAL_ERRORS,MACHINE_ERROR,OTHER_INFO,WARNINGS,SEVERE,PATTERN_VAR,COVERAGE_VAR</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/create_logic_tests-CORE-CRITICAL_ERRORS-MACHINE_ERROR-OTHER_INFO-WARNINGS-SEVERE-PATTERN_VAR-COVERAGE_VAR">1</a></td>
              <td> Rerun</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsible">
      <td>5</td>
      <td colspan="4">diagnose_failures</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="content" colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>TESTCASE_ERRORS,CRITICAL_ERRORS,PATTERN_VAR,COVERAGE_VAR</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/diagnose_failures-TESTCASE_ERRORS-CRITICAL_ERRORS-PATTERN_VAR-COVERAGE_VAR">1</a></td>
              <td> Rerun</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsible">
      <td>6</td>
      <td colspan="4">verify_test_structures</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="content" colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>TESTCASE_ERRORS,MACHINE_ERROR,OTHER_INFO,WARNINGS,SEVERE,COVERAGE_VAR</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/verify_test_structures-TESTCASE_ERRORS-MACHINE_ERROR-OTHER_INFO-WARNINGS-SEVERE-COVERAGE_VAR">1</a></td>
              <td> Open CCR</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsible">
      <td>7</td>
      <td colspan="4">write_toggle_gram</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="content" colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>CORE</td>
              <td><a href="http://etpv/servers/scratch05/gpreeti/python/practice/tc_files1/write_toggle_gram-CORE">1</a></td>
              <td> Fix Testcase</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/g4Lo92zb/

I changed your HTML and JS.

You can collapse a row that uses less code, and makes it look neater.

Be sure when you set the display style property on your element, to set it to the valid display property value.

table `display: table;`

tr `display: table-row;`

td `display: table-cell;`